# DNS server not responding in vpn connection win 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn, dns, internet-connection, pptp

I use win 8.1 and my campus has an intranet network and a vpn(PPTP). to connect to internet, first I have to connect to the intranet(wireless network) and then connect to vpn. But the problem is when connect to vpn, I cannot access internet(in browser and ping with cmd) although I'm connected to vpn and network status show I have internet access. And even after I connect to vpn, I cannot access all local address on the intranet witch I had access before connecting to vpn.
I also tested google dns servers but it couldn't solve my problem.
To access internet I installed ubuntu on vmware and create a vpn connection and I have internet access now so that's my win 8.1 problem.

Any idea what's the problem with windows please? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't found any solution just installed a newer version of win 8.1 and my problem solved.